# Scope for youtube indefinitely load with react-native-google-signin

Tags: react-native, google-signin, react-native-ios

I trying to use signin google in my react-native app, i use the lib [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin).

It's work properly with default scope (profile, email, etc...) but when i attempte to use scope : `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'` for get data of youtube channel the consempt prompt loading indinitely and I do not receive any error when I sign in.

The api is already activate in google cloud plateform.

**Environment**

- react-native = "0.59.4"
- react-native-google-signin = "1.2.2"
- android = 7.0 (physical device : honor 6x with EMUI 5.0.3)
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
- classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
- buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
- minSdkVersion = 16
- compileSdkVersion = 28
- targetSdkVersion = 28
- supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
- googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "15.0.1"